# Check a specific value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I hardly use Excel so not at all familiar with Excel functions.
I want to check whether a specific value is there or not then will do some operation for example, below columns in Excel (total number of rows will be around 1000).

**Sheet1**

```
A   B    C   D    E
--------------------
1   Jan  4   2    0
2   Mar  8   2    0
3   Apr  1   0    8
4   Apr  5   3    8
```

Now on sheet2 I want to show the sum for each month for C, D, E whenever a new row will be added to sheet1 it will automatically update the value for the corresponding month in sheet2

**Sheet2**

```
Month    C   D    E
--------------------
Jan      4   2    0    
Mar      8   2    0    
Apr      6   3    16
```

Can you please let me know how I can achieve this? Which formula I have to use  and how (example) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is on Sheet1 and expected data will be on Sheet2, like this:

```
   | A        B   C    D
=========================
1  | Month    C   D    E
-------------------------
2  | Jan      ?   ?    ?    
3  | Mar      ?   ?    ?    
4  | Apr      ?   ?    ?
```

Put this formula in cell B2 and then drag it to cover the all column and rows for which you need the total.

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!$B:$B,Sheet2!$A1,Sheet1!C:C)
```

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please have a look ?
I am not getting how I can use your formula